# Why is explain_fwrite saying my file marked as non-blocking?

Tags: c, fwrite

I'm trying to write some data to a file. fwrite is returning EAGAIN and fwrite_explain says:

```
2: fwrite(ptr = 0x7F41EFBC09A8, size = 4066, nmemb = 1, fp = 0x02F79200 "/home/user/asdf.txt") failed, Resource temporarily unavailable (11, EAGAIN) because the file descriptor has been marked non-blocking (O_NONBLOCK) and the write would block
2: fwrite(ptr = 0x17ECFFA40, size = 4066, nmemb = 1, fp = 0x02F79200 "/home/user/asdf.txt") failed, No such file or directory (2, ENOENT) because the file is on a file system ("/home", 1% full) which does not support Unix open file semantics, and the file has been deleted from underneath you
2: fwrite(ptr = 0x17ECFF100, size = 4066, nmemb = 1, fp = 0x02F79200 "/home/user/asdf.txt") failed, No such file or directory (2, ENOENT) because the file is on a file system ("/home", 1% full) which does not support Unix open file semantics, and the file has been deleted from underneath you
```

I assume the second set of warnings are invalid (the file never gets removed, it's still there).

I never set my file as non-blocking, and I don't care if it blocks because I want to write the data, regardless of how long it may take. What gives?

The relevant code:

```
fd = fopen(file_to_write, "w");
if (fd == NULL) printf("%d could not open file\n", errno);
n = fwrite((void*)h->bufs[i], write_size, 1, fd);
if (n != write_size) {
    printf("%d: %s\n", errno, explain_fwrite((void*)h->bufs[i], write_size, 1, fd));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fwrite()` returns the number of **items** written, not the **size** of one item or the product of both. (Only if the size of one item happens to be 1, the return value is equal to the number of bytes written.)

The solution will be to compare against the number of items you try to write:

```c
n = fwrite((void*)h->bufs[i], write_size, 1, fd);
if (n != 1) {
```

*Note: It might be wise to set `errno` to zero before a call, as it is not set to zero if the function has no error.*

Comment: Good observation.  And since `fwrite` doesn't touch `errno` when no error occurs, the values observed by OP are just whatever was left over from the last system call that did encounter an error, and have nothing to do with the `fwrite` itself.

Comment: Instead of setting `errno` to 0, the best practice in most cases is instead just to only look at its value if you know that an error actually did occur (as indicated by a return value).

Comment: This also explains OP's own answer: swapping `size` and `nmemb` doesn't change how the write is done, but it does affect the return value, so that the test `if (n != write_size)` becomes correct.

Comment: Fwrite implies that if the returned value isn't the size (and EOF isn't hit), then an error occurred, so short of the nmemb confusion, the check is arguably correct. However, the write was not occurring (file was empty) in the first case, despite fwrite saying that it did write a whole member.

Comment: @BrydonGibson How did you check the written file? Did you close or flush the file stream before checking?

Comment: @thebusybee The function in question calls fclose(), and then `cat myfile.txt` shows nothing. The size of the file is zero according to `ls`.

Comment: Well, then it's time to provide a [example]. Without enough environment we cannot help you further.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this in the process of posting this. Turns out `fwrite` is picky about the order and contents of size and nmemb. I figured I could write **one** *really big* member, but that's not how it works. I have to write `write_size` members each at one byte in size.

Comment: That analysis renders meaningless the [man 3 fread](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fread.3.html) documentation noting that `"This number equals the number of bytes transferred only when size is 1."` `fwrite()` doesn't care if `size` is `1`, `2`, `4`, `8` or `4096`. The `size = 1` is only relevant in comparing the `return` from `fwrite()` It sounds more like you have a couple of processes that have `asdf.txt` accessed in some manner at the same time.

Comment: In that case, is there another error? The write fails even though I am writing one member

Comment: `fwrite( ... "/home/user/asdf.txt") failed, Resource temporarily unavailable ...` points not to a problem with your use of `fwrite()`, but a problem with `"/home/user/asdf.txt"` being "unavailable". That's what makes me suspect that some other process is also using the file and has placed a lock on the file while it does whatever it needs to do with the file. It's impossible to tell what that is given the information available. I would use `fuser /home/user/asdf.txt` to see what else, if anything, is using the file.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The file has no locks, and nothing is using the files other than myself (I am creating the file in this case). Interestingly, when I try to rm the file, it comes up as "write protected". Not sure if this is related

Comment: Yes, that points to a directly related problem. Show `ls -al /home/user/asdf.txt` and let's see the file permissions and UID/GID. Make sure you own the file and have write permission in the first octet, or you are a member of the group and there is write permission in the second octet, or regardless of ownership, there is write permission in the third octet. You also must have execute permission on the directory `/home/user/` or you lack the permission necessary to "descent into" that directory.